# Incorrect Epilines

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I am trying to draw epilines on two images. But only one is shown correctly. See my result below:

[image]

Epilines on the first image (left) seems to be correct since epipole matches with location of second  camera.

But what about the second image? I expected it to be converged somewhere at left, but it is not. **Any idea what is the reason?**

Here is my code : https://gist.github.com/abidrahmank/6146351

I manually checked the validity of fundamental matrix F by the substituting in the equation, `x2'.F.x1 = 0` and it works fine.

**UPDATE:**

Just interchanging input images (img1 and img2) gives me following result which looks more better. (But this trick work only for this image, not any other set of images, so this is not the problem)

[image]

**Why does it happen like this?**

Comment: I'd debug the matches you're getting. Do your provided images use one color per matched pair? it doesn't seem that way, or the matches are very poor.

Comment: No, points are same, but the color to draw the lines are different, just random. I will check the matching.

Comment: It seems you are right. See the new result : http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/3396/djbk.jpg . let me try with other images and get back to you. ( It is a wonder I checked everything except this)

Comment: again, it works only with this image. Also, I thought RANSAC will be possible to find good result even in presence of inliers. in my example, out 846 matches, 108 were selected good by ratio-test, out of which, 84 inliers were found by ransac. So I don't think the problem is with the matches.